# Input field keep telling me field is required despite input is correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The form in the View keep telling me that the field is required despite that I have entered a name. I can't solve this on my own! What could be wrong? The field it's asking for is the FirstName.

This is the Action method in the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateNewAccount([Bind(Include = "ID,FirtsName,LastName,BillingAddress,BillingPostalCode,BillingCity,DeliveryAddress,DeliveryPostalCode,DeliveryCity,EmailAddress,PhoneNumber")] Customers customers)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Add users entity GUID
            //customers.EntityUserInfo = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Customers.Add(customers);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
        }

        return View(customers);
    }
```

And this is the Model:

```
public class Customers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Förnamn")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Efternamn")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Adress - faktura")]
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postnummer - faktura")]
    public string BillingPostalCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Stad - faktura")]
    public string BillingCity { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Adress - försändelse")]
    public string DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postnummer - försändelse")]
    public string DeliveryPostalCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Stad - försändelse")]
    public string DeliveryCity { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-Post")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefonnummer")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the View:

```
@model WebShop_2.Models.Customers

@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateNewAccount";
}

<h2>CreateNewAccount</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Customers</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BillingAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BillingAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BillingAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BillingPostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BillingPostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BillingPostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BillingCity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BillingCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BillingCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliveryAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliveryAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryPostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliveryPostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliveryPostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryCity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliveryCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliveryCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Which field/property?

Comment: Assume its `FirstName`? (your awful `[Bind]` attribute excludes it from binding since you do not include it in the `Include` property (although you do include `FirtsName`

Comment: And since you appear to be wanting to include everything, then just delete it

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why is the [Bind] so awful?! This is auto generated code. But it seems like it's a misspelling of FirstName.

Comment: Why downvote my question?

Comment: Because you should be using a view model (and you ever need a `[Bind]` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you explain this a little bit more? I have not added the Bind myself, if this is so awful, why is it auto generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled 'FirstName', check your model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Förnamn")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

And your Action call with `[Bind]` :

```
[Bind(Include = "ID,FirtsName,
```

Changing it to the following should fix it:

```
[Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,
```

Although as others have pointed out, you should probably use a ViewModel and get rid of the `[Bind]` altogether. [Example here](http://sampathloku.blogspot.be/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html)

Comment: Yes I know that and I wrote that in one of my comments!

Comment: Perfect example about what the `nameof` operator is useful for.

Comment: Thanks for the info about ViewModel